# Naming returned columns in Pandas aggregate function?

Tags: python, group-by, pandas, aggregate-functions

I'm having trouble with Pandas' groupby functionality. I've read [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html), but I can't see to figure out how to apply aggregate functions to multiple columns *and* have custom names for those columns.

This comes very close, but the data structure returned has nested column headings:

```
data.groupby("Country").agg({
  "column1": {"foo": sum()},
  "column2": {"mean": np.mean, "std": np.std}
})
```

(ie. I want to take the mean and std of column2, but return those columns as "mean" and "std")

What am I missing?

Comment: hi @david_chouinard I have the same question actually. Would you think the proposed solution is still best as of today with pandas 17.1?

Answer (score 358, accepted):

## For pandas >= 0.25

The functionality to name returned aggregate columns has been [reintroduced in the master branch](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/26399) and is targeted for pandas 0.25. The new syntax is `.agg(new_col_name=('col_name', 'agg_func')`. Detailed example from the PR linked above:

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'kind': ['cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog'],
   ...:                    'height': [9.1, 6.0, 9.5, 34.0],
   ...:                    'weight': [7.9, 7.5, 9.9, 198.0]})
   ...:

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
  kind  height  weight
0  cat     9.1     7.9
1  dog     6.0     7.5
2  cat     9.5     9.9
3  dog    34.0   198.0

In [4]: df.groupby('kind').agg(min_height=('height', 'min'), 
                               max_weight=('weight', 'max'))
Out[4]:
      min_height  max_weight
kind
cat          9.1         9.9
dog          6.0       198.0
```

It will also be possible to use multiple lambda expressions with this syntax and the two-step rename syntax I suggested earlier (below) as per [this PR](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26430). Again, copying from the example in the PR:

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ['a', 'a'], 'B': [1, 2], 'C': [3, 4]})

In [3]: df.groupby("A").agg({'B': [lambda x: 0, lambda x: 1]})
Out[3]:
         B
  <lambda> <lambda 1>
A
a        0          1
```

and then `.rename()`, or in one go:

```
In [4]: df.groupby("A").agg(b=('B', lambda x: 0), c=('B', lambda x: 1))
Out[4]:
   b  c
A
a  0  0
```

---

## For pandas < 0.25

The currently accepted answer by unutbu describes are great way of doing this in pandas versions <= 0.20. However, as of pandas 0.20, using this method raises a warning indicating that the syntax will not be available in future versions of pandas.

Series:

> FutureWarning: using a dict on a Series for aggregation is deprecated and will be removed in a future version

DataFrames:

> FutureWarning: using a dict with renaming is deprecated and will be removed in a future version

According to the [pandas 0.20 changelog](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/whatsnew.html#deprecate-groupby-agg-with-a-dictionary-when-renaming), the recommended way of renaming columns while aggregating is as follows.

```
# Create a sample data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
                   'B': range(5),
                   'C': range(5)})

# ==== SINGLE COLUMN (SERIES) ====
# Syntax soon to be deprecated
df.groupby('A').B.agg({'foo': 'count'})
# Recommended replacement syntax
df.groupby('A').B.agg(['count']).rename(columns={'count': 'foo'})

# ==== MULTI COLUMN ====
# Syntax soon to be deprecated
df.groupby('A').agg({'B': {'foo': 'sum'}, 'C': {'bar': 'min'}})
# Recommended replacement syntax
df.groupby('A').agg({'B': 'sum', 'C': 'min'}).rename(columns={'B': 'foo', 'C': 'bar'})
# As the recommended syntax is more verbose, parentheses can
# be used to introduce line breaks and increase readability
(df.groupby('A')
    .agg({'B': 'sum', 'C': 'min'})
    .rename(columns={'B': 'foo', 'C': 'bar'})
)
```

Please see the [0.20 changelog](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/whatsnew.html#deprecate-groupby-agg-with-a-dictionary-when-renaming) for additional details.

#### Update 2017-01-03 in response to @JunkMechanic's comment.

With the old style dictionary syntax, it was possible to pass multiple `lambda` functions to `.agg`, since these would be renamed with the key in the passed dictionary:

```
>>> df.groupby('A').agg({'B': {'min': lambda x: x.min(), 'max': lambda x: x.max()}})

    B    
  max min
A        
1   2   0
2   4   3
```

Multiple functions can also be passed to a single column as a list:

```
>>> df.groupby('A').agg({'B': [np.min, np.max]})

     B     
  amin amax
A          
1    0    2
2    3    4
```

However, this does not work with lambda functions, since they are anonymous and all return `<lambda>`, which causes a name collision:

```
>>> df.groupby('A').agg({'B': [lambda x: x.min(), lambda x: x.max]})
SpecificationError: Function names must be unique, found multiple named <lambda>
```

To avoid the `SpecificationError`, named functions can be defined a priori instead of using `lambda`. Suitable function names also avoid calling `.rename` on the data frame afterwards. These functions can be passed with the same list syntax as above:

```
>>> def my_min(x):
>>>     return x.min()

>>> def my_max(x):
>>>     return x.max()

>>> df.groupby('A').agg({'B': [my_min, my_max]})

       B       
  my_min my_max
A              
1      0      2
2      3      4
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. I use this pattern quite often: `df = df.groupby('col_to_grpd_by').agg({'quantity': {
    'mu': lambda series: stats.norm.fit(series)[0],
    'sigma': lambda series: stats.norm.fit(series)[1],
    'active': 'count',
}})` . How would this be handled going forward. Only way I can think of is to define 2 separate functions that return the corresponding elements of the tuple from `stats.norm.fit`. Ignore the fact that I am using `norm`. It could have been a different distribution.

Comment: @JunkMechanic I believe you need to define them first and then pass them as a list. I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Why are they doing away with the `.agg({'B': {'min': lambda x: x.min(), 'max': lambda x: x.max()}})` syntax?  It seems very useful and less messy than having to define named functions if only used for this purpose.

Comment: @sheridp From the 0.20 changelog linked above: "However, .agg(..) can also accept a dict that allows ‘renaming’ of the result columns. This is a complicated and confusing syntax, as well as not consistent between Series and DataFrame. We are deprecating this ‘renaming’ functionaility."

Comment: @JoelOstblom Having run your example, I am struggling with the syntax to access the grouped data frame. What syntax would I use to access the dataframe by the grouped values? Something like df['A'] to list [1,2]. What syntax would I use to plot 'foo' vs 'A'? Something like df.plot('A','foo').

Comment: @astromonerd After applying an aggregation function to a grouped data frame, the returned object is a standard data frame that is indexed by the grouped column(s). If you find the index cumbersome, you can reset it with `reset_index()` and then access the index variable(s) as columns instead. If something is still unclear, please create a new question and feel free to link it here.

Comment: @joelostblom - it looks like this option from your Update section: `df.groupby('A').agg({'B': [lambda x: x.min(), lambda x: x.max()]})` now works by automatically adding suffixes to the `lambda` column names.  
  
@JunkMechanic, @sheridp - an option similar to this old behaviour can be got from defining the named aggregations in a dictionary and then unpacking in the `agg` method. E.g.: `df.groupby('A').agg(**{"min": ("B", lambda x: x.min()),"max": ("B", lambda x: x.max())})`

Answer (score 148):

This will drop the outermost level from the hierarchical column index:

```
df = data.groupby(...).agg(...)
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
```

If you'd like to keep the outermost level, you can use the ravel() function on the multi-level column to form new labels:

```
df.columns = ["_".join(x) for x in df.columns.ravel()]
```

***update***:
in newer pandas instead of `.ravel()` use `.tolist()` or `.to_numpy()` `use df.columns = ["_".join(x) for x in df.columns.tolist()]`

---

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.rpy.common as com
import numpy as np

data = com.load_data('Loblolly')
print(data.head())
#     height  age Seed
# 1     4.51    3  301
# 15   10.89    5  301
# 29   28.72   10  301
# 43   41.74   15  301
# 57   52.70   20  301

df = data.groupby('Seed').agg(
    {'age':['sum'],
     'height':['mean', 'std']})
print(df.head())
#       age     height           
#       sum        std       mean
# Seed                           
# 301    78  22.638417  33.246667
# 303    78  23.499706  34.106667
# 305    78  23.927090  35.115000
# 307    78  22.222266  31.328333
# 309    78  23.132574  33.781667

df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
print(df.head())
```

yields

```
      sum        std       mean
Seed                           
301    78  22.638417  33.246667
303    78  23.499706  34.106667
305    78  23.927090  35.115000
307    78  22.222266  31.328333
309    78  23.132574  33.781667
```

Alternatively, to keep the first level of the index:

```
df = data.groupby('Seed').agg(
    {'age':['sum'],
     'height':['mean', 'std']})
df.columns = ["_".join(x) for x in df.columns.ravel()]
```

yields

```
      age_sum   height_std  height_mean
Seed                           
301        78    22.638417    33.246667
303        78    23.499706    34.106667
305        78    23.927090    35.115000
307        78    22.222266    31.328333
309        78    23.132574    33.781667
```

Comment: Works, but gets rid of the grouped by column since its in level 0 :(

Comment: Note that this syntax will be deprecated in future versions of pandas. Details are in the [0.20 changelog](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/whatsnew.html#deprecate-groupby-agg-with-a-dictionary-when-renaming), which I summarized in my answer.

Comment: @Mugen sorry for the (very) late response, but this is an easy fix, you can just do `df.columns = ['_'.join(x) if isinstance(x,tuple) else x for x in df.columns.ravel()]` which takes advantage of the fact that only the aggregated columns will be tuples, so if you have other tuples in your column names, then exercise caution here.

Answer (score 13):

I agree with the OP that it seems more natural and consistent to name and define the output columns in the same place (e.g. as is done with [tidyverse's `summarize` in R](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html)), but a work-around in pandas for now is to create the new columns with desired names via [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) *before* doing the aggregation:

```
data.assign(
    f=data['column1'],
    mean=data['column2'],
    std=data['column2']
).groupby('Country').agg(dict(f=sum, mean=np.mean, std=np.std)).reset_index()
```

(Using [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) turns `'Country'`, `'f'`, `'mean'`, and `'std'` all into regular columns with a separate integer index.)

Answer (score 8):

If you want to have a behavior similar to JMP, creating column titles that keep all info from the multi index you can use:

```
newidx = []
for (n1,n2) in df.columns.ravel():
    newidx.append("%s-%s" % (n1,n2))
df.columns=newidx
```

It will change your dataframe from:

```
    I                       V
    mean        std         first
V
4200.0  25.499536   31.557133   4200.0
4300.0  25.605662   31.678046   4300.0
4400.0  26.679005   32.919996   4400.0
4500.0  26.786458   32.811633   4500.0
```

to

```
    I-mean      I-std       V-first
V
4200.0  25.499536   31.557133   4200.0
4300.0  25.605662   31.678046   4300.0
4400.0  26.679005   32.919996   4400.0
4500.0  26.786458   32.811633   4500.0
```

Comment: You can also add a conditional check to get the same column name if there is no 2nd row `    if n2 == '':
        new_col_name.append("%s" % n1)
    else:
        new_col_name.append("%s_%s" % (n1, n2))`

Comment: u don't need `.ravel()`, i think `df.columns` is enough!

Answer (score 1):

With the inspiration of @Joel Ostblom

For those who already have a workable dictionary for merely aggregation, you can use/modify the following code for the newer version aggregation, separating aggregation and renaming part. Please be aware of the nested dictionary if there are more than 1 item.

```
def agg_translate_agg_rename(input_agg_dict):
    agg_dict = {}
    rename_dict = {}
    for k, v in input_agg_dict.items():
        if len(v) == 1:
            agg_dict[k] = list(v.values())[0]
            rename_dict[k] = list(v.keys())[0]
        else:
            updated_index = 1
            for nested_dict_k, nested_dict_v in v.items():
                modified_key = k + "_" + str(updated_index)
                agg_dict[modified_key] = nested_dict_v
                rename_dict[modified_key] = nested_dict_k
                updated_index += 1
    return agg_dict, rename_dict

one_dict = {"column1": {"foo": 'sum'}, "column2": {"mean": 'mean', "std": 'std'}}
agg, rename = agg_translator_aa(one_dict)
```

We get

```
agg = {'column1': 'sum', 'column2_1': 'mean', 'column2_2': 'std'}
rename = {'column1': 'foo', 'column2_1': 'mean', 'column2_2': 'std'}
```

Please let me know if there is a smarter way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: seems like the only viable solution 4 years later.

Comment: or also this should work `df.columns = ['_'.join(a) for a in df.columns.to_flat_index()]`

Answer (score 1):

such as this kind of dataframe, there are two levels of thecolumn name:

```
 shop_id  item_id   date_block_num item_cnt_day       
                                  target              
0   0       30          1            31
```

we can use this code：

`df.columns = [col[0] if col[-1]=='' else col[-1] for col in df.columns.values]`

result is:

```
 shop_id  item_id   date_block_num target              
0   0       30          1            31
```

Comment: I like this method the most. With a little modification I got the following:[col[0] if col[-1]=='' else col[-1]+'_'+col[0] for col in path_info.columns.values]