# Renaming Column Names in Pandas Groupby function

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, rename

Q1) I want to do a groupby, SQL-style aggregation and **rename the output column**:

Example dataset:

```
    ID     Region  count
0  100       Asia      2
1  101     Europe      3
2  102         US      1
3  103     Africa      5
4  100     Russia      5
5  101  Australia      7
6  102         US      8
7  104       Asia     10
8  105     Europe     11
9  110     Africa     23
```

I want to group the observations of this dataset by `ID` and `Region` and summing the `count` for each group. So I used something like this...

```
>>> print(df.groupby(['ID','Region'],as_index=False).count().sum())

    ID     Region  count
0  100       Asia      2
1  100     Russia      5
2  101  Australia      7
3  101     Europe      3
4  102         US      9
5  103     Africa      5
6  104       Asia     10
7  105     Europe     11
8  110     Africa     23
```

On using `as_index=False` I am able to get "SQL-Like" output. My problem is that I am unable to **rename the aggregate variable `count`** here. So in SQL if wanted to do the above thing I would do something like this:

```
select ID, Region, sum(count) as Total_Numbers
from df
group by ID, Region
order by ID, Region
```

As we see, it's very easy for me to **rename the aggregate variable `count`** to `Total_Numbers` in SQL. I wanted to do the same thing in Pandas but unable to find such an option in group-by function. Can somebody help?

---

The second question (more of an observation):

Q2) Is it possible to directly use column names in Pandas dataframe functions without enclosing them in quotes?

I understand that the variable names are strings, so have to be inside quotes, but I see if use them outside dataframe function and as an attribute we don't require them to be inside quotes. Like `df.ID.sum()` etc. It's only when we use it in a DataFrame function like `df.sort()` or `df.groupby` we have to use it inside quotes. This is actually a bit of pain as in SQL or in SAS or other languages we simply use the variable name without quoting them. Any suggestion on this?

Kindly reply to both questions (Q1 is the main, Q2 more of an opinion).

Answer (score 99, accepted):

For the first question I think answer would be:

```
<your DataFrame>.rename(columns= {'count':'Total_Numbers'})
```

or

```
<your DataFrame>.columns = ['ID', 'Region', 'Total_Numbers']
```

if it is Pandas Series we have

```
<your Series>.rename("Total_Numbers")
```

As for second one I'd say the answer would be no. It's possible to use it like 'df.ID' because of [python datamodel](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html):

> Attribute references are translated to lookups in this dictionary,
> e.g., m.x is equivalent to m.**dict**["x"]

Comment: Thxs for the response.The rename thing helped, except that I guess in the first syntax we need to also mention the columns=.. so, <your DataFrame>.rename(columns={'count':'Total_Numbers'}). Else it would take it for index and doesn't change the column name. Second thing works perfectly, but if one or two variables need to be renamed then I guess first one is more convenient rather than mentioning all variable names in second syntax. 
I was hoping if there is something in groupby but looks like there isn't. Also I understand pandas df is a dict intrinsic.Was hoping for some flexibility in Panda

Answer (score 45):

The current (as of version 0.20) method for changing column names after a groupby operation is to chain the `rename` method. See [this deprecation note](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.20.0.html#deprecate-groupby-agg-with-a-dictionary-when-renaming) in the documentation for more detail.

## Deprecated Answer as of pandas version 0.20

This is the first result in google and although the top answer works it does not really answer the question. There is a [better answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078325/naming-returned-columns-in-pandas-aggregate-function) and a long [discussion on github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9052) about the full functionality of passing dictionaries to the `agg` method.

These answers unfortunately do not exist in the documentation but the general format for grouping, aggregating and then renaming columns uses a dictionary of dictionaries. The keys to the outer dictionary are column names that are to be aggregated. The inner dictionaries have keys that the new column names with values as the aggregating function.

Before we get there, let's create a four column DataFrame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : list('wwwwxxxx'), 
                   'B':list('yyzzyyzz'), 
                   'C':np.random.rand(8), 
                   'D':np.random.rand(8)})

   A  B         C         D
0  w  y  0.643784  0.828486
1  w  y  0.308682  0.994078
2  w  z  0.518000  0.725663
3  w  z  0.486656  0.259547
4  x  y  0.089913  0.238452
5  x  y  0.688177  0.753107
6  x  z  0.955035  0.462677
7  x  z  0.892066  0.368850
```

Let's say we want to group by columns `A, B` and aggregate column `C` with `mean` and `median` and aggregate column `D` with `max`. The following code would do this.

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B']).agg({'C':['mean', 'median'], 'D':'max'})

            D         C          
          max      mean    median
A B                              
w y  0.994078  0.476233  0.476233
  z  0.725663  0.502328  0.502328
x y  0.753107  0.389045  0.389045
  z  0.462677  0.923551  0.923551
```

This returns a DataFrame with a hierarchical index. The original question asked about renaming the columns in the same step. This is possible using a dictionary of dictionaries:

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B']).agg({'C':{'C_mean': 'mean', 'C_median': 'median'}, 
                            'D':{'D_max': 'max'}})

            D         C          
        D_max    C_mean  C_median
A B                              
w y  0.994078  0.476233  0.476233
  z  0.725663  0.502328  0.502328
x y  0.753107  0.389045  0.389045
  z  0.462677  0.923551  0.923551
```

This renames the columns all in one go but still leaves the hierarchical index which the top level can be dropped with `df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)`.

Comment: later in 2017/2018 changes were made, resulting in "nested renamer is not supported" due to GH 15931 - deprecation of renaming keys.

Comment: Not working anymore pal..