# How to perform aggregate options on one groupby column, giving two column outputs

Tags: python, pandas

I am performing a bunch of aggregate stats on a groupby data frame.  For one column in particular, `ios_id`, I would like a count and a distinct count.  I'm not sure how o output this to two seaparate columns with different names.  As of right now, the distinct count just overwrites the count.

How do I output both the distinct count and the count for the ios_id column to two separate columns?

```
df_new = df.groupby('video_id').agg({"ios_id": np.count_nonzero,
                                     "ios_id": pd.Series.nunique,
                                     "feed_position": np.average,
                                     "time_watched": np.sum,
                                     "video_length": np.sum}).sort('ios_id', ascending=False)
```

Comment: `ios_id` is a reference to the column on which to perform the statistic on.  If I change the names then there is nothing to reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. Note the nested dictionary structure for iOS_id.

```
df_new = df.groupby('video_id').agg({"ios_id": {"count": "count",
                                                "distinct": "unique"},
                                     "feed_position": np.average,
                                     "time_watched": np.sum,
                                     "video_length": np.sum})
```

For more details, please refer to [Naming returned columns in Pandas aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078325/naming-returned-columns-in-pandas-aggregate-function):