# Getting unique counts for selected columns in dataframe with groupby using Python

Tags: python, aggregation

**My dataframe is as follows:**

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','a','b','c'], 'B':['x','x','x','x'],'C':['1','2','3','4'], 'D':[0,0,0,0]})
gb_a=df.groupby(['A'], as_index=False)
```

**My desired output:**

```
A    unique_b    unique_c
a       1          2
b       1          1
c       1          1
```

**I have tried the following:**

```
gb_a['B','C'].agg({'B':pd.Series.nunique, 'C':pd.Series.nunique})
gb_a['B','C'].agg({'unique_b':pd.Series.nunique, 'unique_c':pd.Series.nunique})
gb_a['B','C'].agg({'B': {'unique_b':pd.Series.nunique}, 'C': {'unique_c':pd.Series.nunique}})
```

**Error I am getting:**

```
KeyError: ('B', 'C')
```

**Questions**

Is it possible to fix it in above technique?

I know I can do it individually and then merging as follows:

```
out_df=gb_a['B'].agg({'unique_b':pd.Series.nunique})
out_df= pd.merge(out_df,gb_a['C'].agg({'unique_c':pd.Series.nunique}), on='A', how='inner')
```

But I am supposed to do different  aggregation on selected columns (a lot of columns). Do not want to merge that many times on a large data.

I am using Python 2.7

Thanks.

p.s. I have read different answers on similar topic. e.g.

[Naming returned columns in Pandas aggregate function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078325/naming-returned-columns-in-pandas-aggregate-function)

Comment: It's not clear how you went from that df to that output.

Comment: I would like to cont the unique values of B and C group by A. Sorry if I was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Per [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#id35),
SeriesGroupBy objects have a nunique method. Therefore, you can aggregate `gb_a` using

```
gb_a.agg({'B': 'nunique', 'C': 'nunique'})
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], 'B': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], 'C': [
                  '1', '2', '3', '4'], 'D': [0, 0, 0, 0]})
gb_a = df.groupby(['A'], as_index=False)
result = gb_a.agg({'B': 'nunique', 'C': 'nunique'})
result = result.rename(columns={'B':'unique_b', 'C':'unique_c'})
print(result)
```

prints

```
   A  unique_c  unique_b
0  a         2         1
1  b         1         1
2  c         1         1
```