# Python agregation function

Tags: python, data-analysis

I need to modify my code:

```
db_profit_platform=db[['Source','Device','Country','Profit']]
db_profit_final=db_profit_platform.groupby(['Source','Device','Country'])['Profit'].apply(sum).reset_index()
```

Now I need to add Bid and get average bid after group by (different aggregations for different columns):
to get: Source   Device   Country   SumProfit   Average Bid

How can I do it? (and maybe I will need more aggregations) Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `agg` function, here a minimal working example

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

size = 10

db = pd.DataFrame({
    'Source': np.random.randint(1, 3, size=size),
    'Device': np.random.randint(1, 3, size=size),
    'Country': np.random.randint(1, 3, size=size),
    'Profit': np.random.randn(size),
    'Bid': np.random.randn(size)
})

db.groupby(["Source", "Device", "Country"]).agg(
    sum_profit=("Profit", "sum"),
    avg_bid=("Bid", "mean")
)
```

See the official documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19078325/8227062) question